# Using the Calculus of Constructions as a metalogic

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, type-theory

Usually the Calculus of Construction is used via the Curry-Howard isomorphism, which makes it equivalent to intuitionistic first order logic. But what I am interested in is to use CoC as a metalogic instead and to encode the syntax, axioms and inference rules of a different logic inside it. For clarity, I'm using the following syntax for CoC:
$$
A := * \mid \square \mid x \mid A \ A \mid \lambda x : A . A \mid \Pi x : A . A
$$

Now, for encoding propositional calculus, we could define the syntax by providing specific elements of appropriate types:
$$
\Rightarrow : \Pi p : * . \Pi q : * . * \\
\lnot : \Pi p : * . * \\
$$
where we assume that $\Rightarrow$ is right associative and binds stronger than $\to$ in type expressions.

Then we can define MP and the axioms of propositional logic
$$
\textit{MP} : \Pi p : * . \Pi q : * . p \Rightarrow q \to p \to q \\
\textit{AX1} : \Pi p : * . \Pi q : * . p \Rightarrow q \Rightarrow p \\
\textit{AX2} : \Pi p : * . \Pi q : * . \Pi r : * . (p \Rightarrow q \Rightarrow r) \Rightarrow (p \Rightarrow q) \Rightarrow p \Rightarrow r \\
\textit{AX3} : \Pi p : * . \Pi q : * . (\lnot p \Rightarrow \lnot q) \Rightarrow q \Rightarrow p
$$

With this, we can also write proofs. For example we can prove $p \Rightarrow p$ as follows:
$$
p_1 := \lambda p : * . \lambda q : * . \textit{MP} \ (p \Rightarrow q \Rightarrow p) \ ((p \Rightarrow q) \Rightarrow p \Rightarrow p) \ (\textit{AX2} \ p \ q \ p) \ (\textit{AX1} \ p \ q) \\
p_1 : \Pi p : * . \Pi q : * . (p \Rightarrow q) \Rightarrow p \Rightarrow p \\
p_2 := \lambda p : * . \lambda q : * . \textit{MP} \ (p \Rightarrow q \Rightarrow p) \ (p \Rightarrow p) \ (p_1 \ p \ (q \Rightarrow p)) \ (\textit{AX1} \ p \ q) \\
p_2 : \Pi p : * . \Pi q : * . p \Rightarrow p \\
$$

The above proof exposes also the use or $q$ as a kind of dummy variable, but can be updated to use only $p$ by defining $p_3 := \lambda p : * . p_2 \ p \ p$.

**And now the questions**

- Is this line of research worthwhile? Is it something already well known and understood? Any references would be extremely useful.
- I'm not sure how to extend the above to first order logic, i.e. how to define $\forall$.

**Update:** I have two ideas for handling $\forall$, which depend on whether predicates are taken to be polymorphic or not:
$$
\forall_1 := \lambda t:*.\lambda P:t\to *.\Pi x:t.(P \ x) \\
\forall_2 := \lambda P:(\Pi t:*.\Pi x:t.*).\Pi u:*.\Pi x:u.(P \ u \ x) \\
$$
So my second question becomes: which of these two (if any) makes more sense for defining $\forall$?

Comment: I read a little to quickly your title as "metalurgic constructions" and was ready to write: "you are not on the right site" :)

Comment: Re: your first question. Using CiC (an extension to CC) as a meta-logic is done all the time. See for example https://www.comp.nus.edu.sg/~henz/publications/pdf/CPP2011.pdf or https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/slf-current/toc.html or https://iris-project.org